# SimpleAudioEngine non-exception breakpoint

Tags: audio, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

[breakpoint http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60578443/exception_breakpoint.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60578443/exception_breakpoint.png)
[exception http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60578443/simpleaudioengine_exception.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60578443/simpleaudioengine_exception.png)

I've met a issue in SimpleAudioEngine in cocos2d.

As the image shows,I added a breakpoint that pauses the code every time exception comes.Then every time I need to play audio effect,it pauses.Also there are several breakpoints of them.That's kind of inconvenient.How can I avoid these exceptions with exceptions I need enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your exception to Objective-C rather than all. That fixed it for me.

[image: Breakpoint]

Comment: Glad I could help! Make sure to tick accept if the answer worked for you.